# Does anyone run Visual Studio on EC2 for their primary workplace?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, amazon-ec2, visual-studio-2019

Our company decided to virtualize everything into EC2 and that includes our development machines. The machines are instance type T3 large and we are using Visual Studio 2019 16.9 as of this morning. The performance seems to be horrible for all of our developers. Every time we build, node takes over the CPU and then stays high. Intellisense is laggy.

We do not have any extensions running, just the stock VS2019 install. The solutions is pretty small. It consists of 3 C# projects; DTOs, Controllers, and a Web Site.

I wonder if this has something to do with EBS being relatively slow.

Has anyone had better success?

Comment: VS is something I would not run on a cloud VM (or even a local VM really) as your primary mode of development. It is a resource hog for one and it is also imperative it is not too "lagy". You can kill the team performance. I wonder if it was a developer that made this choice or someone who does not have to write code in VS on a day-to-day basis? Good luck and I hope you get your issues resolved.

Comment: Also I think this question might be a better fit for [su] or [sf] as it is dealing with hardware or possibly network I/O? Check those sites to see if there is a better fit as [so] really deals with code as opposed to IDE performance.

Comment: Those are great points.  I will ask the question on those other boards. I actually made the choice to move it to EC2. Since going remote, we no longer have a dedicated Dev Server and to make networking easier, I figured putting everything into EC2 behind RD Gateway would simplify trying to get everyone a shared set of resources. I never imagined a virtual environment would tank VS so bad.